# Cut command in Python via subprocess module

Tags: python, subprocess, cut

How to run the following line ?

```
subprocess.Popen(('cut', '-d', '" "', '-f', '1'), stdin=out_2.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

It returns this error:

```
cut: the delimiter must be a single character
```

Comment: Do you really need to invoke `cut` in this case?

Comment: oh yes, what devnull is saying:  use python's split() command instead.

Answer (score 3):

Don't double quote:

```
subprocess.Popen(('cut', '-d', ' ', '-f', '1'), stdin=out_2.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
                               ^^^
```

is sufficient !

Comment: The error message doesn't appear anymore but the script doesn't work

Comment: Then ask another question giving us more information !

Comment: [sscce](http://www.sscce.org/) ? Asking a **new** question, with expected result ?